# read_csv reads all input into first column for some rows

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to read a csv file, which I downloaded from [City of Chicago](https://data.cityofchicago.org/Public-Safety/Crimes-2001-to-present/ijzp-q8t2/data) as a csv file into a dataframe. However, for many rows all data gets read into the first column like row 2. If I delete those rows, there are only 5% of the data left. Does anyone have an idea what to do? 
Also when opening the csv file as txt, the rows that do not read correctly have a leading ". I dont know if that would cause the issue.

```py
crime_df = pd.read_csv('ChicagoCrime.csv')
crime_df.head(10)
```

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAw9h.png)

Comment: Please post your code and data  as text,  not images.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: I downloaded the file as a CSV for Excel and didn't get an issue. I would recommend this unless you really don't want to download it again.

[image: Screenshot of DF Head]

*My first suggestion is to specify more arguments in the read_csv function to help it out. You may try specifying a delimiter, specify the engine to use, set parse_dates to True, etc. Check out https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html for all available arguments.*

Comment: I tried it with the csv for excel file, but it is the same result. However, I didn't get this error message before: DtypeWarning: Columns (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,14,18) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
  interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)

Comment: Have you tried specifying data types or specifying low_memory=True? If so what was the result?